# Cortex M0+ returns to wrong position in thread mode after interrupting sleep

Tags: c, atmel, cortex-m

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious here but has anyone else experienced any issues with the Cortex M0+ (or any of the Cortex M range) returning from an ISR to a somewhat random position in thread mode after being woken up from sleep mode (eg not returning to the line below the WFI instruction). It seems to wake up in the middle of the code, like in the middle of a for loop or the middle of a function. I'm using the ATSAMD218A microcontroller and have been using the debugger in Atmel Studio 7. I've attempted to isolate the problem and have noticed the following:

- It only occurs when the device is put to sleep, when the device is interrupted while it is awake the ISR always returns to the right place.
- The ISR always returns to the same (incorrect) position in the code, if I comment out that function or piece of code then it begins returning to another incorrect position
- I've unsuccessfully inserted delays and NOPs to try determine if it is timing related or clock cycle related but it still always returns to the same (incorrect) position
- I have tried implementing interrupts using both direct register access as well as using the Arduino Interrupts library.
- It occurs in both idle and standby mode (sleep and deep sleep)
- While looking at the assembly instructions during debugging, right before the ISR is exited, the 'bx lr' instruction is called which is supposed to branch to the link register. The link register contains a value called EXC_RETURN which indicates the return behavior, which in my case is 0xFFFFFFF9 (return to thread mode). I can't however find the actual memory address that it returns to anywhere. The memory address isn't in any of the core registers R0-R15.

I have been reading the ARMv6 Architecture Reference Manual as well as the Cortex M0+ Generic User Guide. Not quite sure what's going on and any debugging suggestions would be much appreciated. Does anyone have a better understanding of the exception handling of the Cortex M series and could point me in the right direction to find the memory address that thread mode returns to after an ISR. I could supply code if you'd like but even a simple piece of code that does nothing but count in a loop, sleep and then wake up causes trouble.

EDIT
I've added the relevant code below. It is the most stripped back version (*stripped) that still causes problems. I haven't included the RTC code functions (uses the DS3231RTC library) as I'm fairly certain they don't have any effect. If you think I should upload more let me know.

```
void configInterrupt(void){
  NVIC_DisableIRQ(EIC_IRQn);
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EIC_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(EIC_IRQn, 0);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(EIC_IRQn);

  // Enable GCLK for IEC (External Interrupt Controller)
  GCLK->CLKCTRL.reg = (uint16_t) (GCLK_CLKCTRL_CLKEN | GCLK_CLKCTRL_GEN_GCLK0    | GCLK_CLKCTRL_ID(GCM_EIC));

  EIC->WAKEUP.reg |= (1 << 0);
  EIC->CONFIG[0].reg |= 0x2;                    // falling edge
  pinConfig(16,INPUT,UP);                     // custom 'pinMode' function
  PORT->Group[0].PINCFG[16].bit.PMUXEN = 1; // enable peripheral muxing
  PORT->Group[0].PMUX[8].bit.PMUXE = 0x0;       // function A (EIC) = 0x0
  EIC->INTENSET.reg = EIC_INTENSET_EXTINT(1 << 0);
  EIC->CTRL.bit.ENABLE = 1;
}

void EIC_Handler(void){   
  RTC_FLAG = 1;           // my debug breakpoint is here, at this point the stack has already been pushed and I can see the PC value that will be popped off
  int_count++;
  EIC->INTFLAG.reg = 1 << 0;
}

void setup() {
  configInterrupt();                
  configureRTC();
  RTC_FLAG = 1;
}

void loop() {
  if (RTC_FLAG == 1) {
    RTC_FLAG = 0;
    setNextAlarm();
  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i <= WINDOW-1 ; i++) {
        String data = "";

        rawVal  = 0;     // data gets read from sensor here (stripped)
        data += String(rawVal);   
        data += ",";

        distance = 0;    // distance calculated from rawVal here (stripped)
        data += String(distance);
        data += ",";

        mean = 0;        // mean calculated in a function here (stripped)
        data += String(mean);
        data += ",";

        data += String(int_count);    // ISR returns here 
        // Data gets written to file here (stripped)
}

  SCB->SCR |= SCB_SCR_SLEEPDEEP_Msk;
  __DSB();
  __WFI();
}
```

Comment: Can you post up the code you were using and the points that you think it is failing?

Comment: _"I can't however find the actual memory address that it returns to anywhere"_ - See B1.5.6 "Exception entry behavior" in the ARMv6-M ARM; it's on the stack. What does the ISR code look like?

Comment: I doubt this is an arm thing, likely a chip thing, need to read the manual for the device with a particular focus on everything it says about when it goes to sleep.  What is preserved, what is not, if there is a recommendation for how and where to sleep, etc.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks! Found that information and I can see where the 'restored' PC value is coming from (popped off of the stack) but I'm not sure I can debug how its getting pushed onto the stack as I can only add a debug break point during the ISR, at which point the stack pushing has already occurred.

Comment: @dwelch Yeah I've had a look through the SAM D21G datasheet but I don't believe there is anything in there, but correct me if I'm wrong. I had a good look through Chapter 11 (Processor and Architecture) as well as Chapter 16 (Power Manager), where they discuss the sleep mode controller but don't mention anything about returning from an ISR or an exception.

Comment: this line: `for (int i = 0 ; i <= WINDOW-1 ; i++)`  would be much clearer if written as: `for (int i = 0 ; i < WINDOW ; i++)`

Comment: when stopped at the beginning of the ISR function, then examine the prior (assembly) instructions AND what is actually on the stack.  (using the stack pointer as a reference to determine where on the stack to look

Comment: do you have an execution trace tools?  if so, just keep the last 'x' instructions in the trace, then you should be able to see exactly where the return address was set AND the timing AND exactly how the return address was popped

Comment: Cheers for the help guys. I'm going to open a new question as I've followed the assembly instructions and discovered the pushing and popping of the stack is all operating as I'd expected. Instead I've discovered that my code isn't jumping to the ISR from where I thought it was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115323/discussion-between-user3629249-and-lance-molyneaux).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to implement the same snippet using Atmel ASF framework, look at the registers the API sets and what order.  They will also usually reference errata and implement a work around.

Load the low power example project, it switches between power modes, and wakes on the xplained board button press.  If that can hop between modes on your board, you know it's not the part.  You might have to move the wake pin to something to match your hardware.